# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Mac - Unable to install Worklight from the Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

When I try to download it I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio
>   6.0.0.201306140657 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140657)   Missing requirement: IBM Web Editor Common 1.2.0.v20130514_1852 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common 1.2.0.v20130514_1852) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [4.2.1,5.0.0)' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Rich Page Editor Base 1.2.0.v20130516_0814 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130516_0814)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.html [1.0.400.v20130504_0525]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Rich Page Editor - HTML 1.0.400.v20130504_0525 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.html 1.0.400.v20130504_0525)
>       To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common [1.0.0,2.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Rich Page Editor 6.0.0.201306140658 (com.ibm.imp.rpe.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140658)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.feature.feature.group 1.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.0.0.201306140657 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140657)
>       To: com.ibm.imp.rpe.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0

I have downloaded it on my windows 7 laptop no problem. Is this my fault or IBM's? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Eclipse version? Java EE 4.2.2 or 4.3?

I've downloaded and installed on both my Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.8 with Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 for Developers (the currently supported version together with Eclipse Classic 4.2.2).

- Make sure that the option to "contact all update sites during install to find required software" is checked (in Help >> Install New Software...).

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.4. I am on Java EE 4.3 right now. I have tried in the past with 4.2.2 but will try again.

Comment: 4.3 is not supported at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working on a Mac OS X 10.8.4 using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Juno SR2 4.2.2) by using the Eclipse Marketplace.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2

Used this tutorial:

http://clearblade.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/installing-ibm-worklight-v6-adt-rtc-mtww/

[image]